# How to open multiple writable files in a for loop based on supplied file containing filenames

Tags: file

Can someone fix the below python code please?
I intend to open writable files to dump something in each of these file later (that code is not here) with the following names,

aaa2021-02-02.rpt

bbb2021-02-02.rpt

ccc2021-02-02.rpt

My code starts here:

```
f_name = list()
with open("files_names") as f :
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
        for line in lines:
                f_name.append(line)

for m in range(len(f_name)):
        f_name[m]       = open("f_name[m]{}.rpt".format(date.today()), "w+")

#content of the file, files_names:
#aaa
#bbb
#ccc
```